# Getting a selected object from a ListView

Tags: java, listview, fxml

I am wanting to select an object from a JList and use a button to add this object to another Jlist. This is the code that is ran when the button which is meant to add the selected object to the JList is clicked. It is coming up with an error saying that the Object found is of type, Object, when an Object of type, Movie, is required.

```
 public void selectObject(ActionEvent event) {
        Movie selectedMovie = (Movie)movieJList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

  }
```

Comment: Could you also add to your question the code from movieJList you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: In java 8, `getSelectionModel()` returns a `ListSelectionModel`. There is no `getSelectedItem()` in that API. Can you please provide how `movieJList` is instantiated?

Comment: I have managed to get it to work by casting the object as movie so that it is expecting an object of type movie. I am now struggling to add this object to another list

Comment: How? The code as you posted does not work. Just like @Ascalonian said.

Comment: I have update my code to show the change which made it work

Comment: I still dont get, how you get this to work, if `movieJList` is a `JList` because `movieJList.getSelectionModel()` does not provide `getSelectedValue()`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried creating a JList and JList itself provides the `getSelectedValue()` Method that returns the selected value. Type depending on the type of the JList.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue()

Is it that what you need? Otherwise please post more of your code.

Comment: I am not sure if you posted Java 7 API link by mistake and meant Java 8

Comment: I am using Java 8 and this works, but thx you are right. Now it’s Java 11 :)

Comment: I am also using Java 8 (1.8.0_211) and that API is not there - nor is it in Oracle's API JavaDocs

Comment: What is not there? I am not sure if we talk about the same thing. `JList` provides a method called `getSelectedValue()`. `getSelectionModel()` does not.